# Alphabetize a queue using qsort

Tags: c, queue, qsort, alphabetized

I'm trying to use qsort to alphabetize a Queue (linked list), but I'm getting a Segmentation Fault when I run it. I believe the problem is in the compare function, but I don't see a way to debug it, so here I am.

```
int compare (const void*va, const void*vb)
{
    link a=(link)va;
    link b=(link)vb;
    int criterium_1 = strcmp(a->item->text,b->item->text);
    if (criterium_1!=0) return criterium_1;
    return (a->item->sender)-(b->item->sender);
}


int list ( Queue list, int sort )
{
    Queue q = list ;
    link t;
    int i=0;
    link *sorted = (link*) malloc ( sizeof(link) * list->size );

    if ( list == NULL )
    {
        puts("NULL");
        return 0;
    }

    for ( t = q->head ; t!=NULL ; t=t->next )
    {
        sorted[i]=t;
        i++;
    }

    if( sort==1 )
    qsort( sorted , q->size , sizeof(link), compare );

    for ( i=0 ; i<q->size ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d %d %s", sorted[i]->item->receiver, sorted[i]->item->sender, sorted[i]->item->text ) ;
    }

    free(sorted);       /* Esta a libertar o que esta la dentro tambem? */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `link *a = (link *)va;` assuming that `link` is a typedef for a structure.  If not, please show the definition of `link`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. (I asume that `link` and `Queue` are pointer-to-tructure types.) Could you please post the full code, ideally with example data for which the code fails? As to debugging, you can usually do a minimal debugging by compiling with debug data (`-g` for gcc) and then just running the program in a debugger. This will show you where the crash occured and also give you a call stack, i.e. where each function was called from.